# How to update a postgres database in kubernetes using scripts [CI/CD]?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I have one postgres database deployed in kubernetes attached to a pvc [with **RWX** access mode]. What is the right way to update (create table) the database through my CI/CD instead of logging in to the pod and running queries [Without deleting the pvc] ?

Comment: Am I right that you would like to modify data directly on that PVC without using postgre clientto connect to the server?  What is the background reason for that?

Comment: I need to modify tables and add tables without logging in to the pod. I want something like deploying a new updated sql file or similar solutions. So whenever I update the sql file and deploy the db gets updated and I don't want that to affect the data stored in pvc.

Comment: So instead of connecting to the PostgreSQL Database Server via an interactive terminal program called psql and via the pgAdmin application in order to run DDL/DML queries you merely would like to update some "sql files" on that PVC (without recreating PVC) . Am I right?

Comment: yes. So the changes should happen when I update the sql files and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the background reason for your question is how to deploy DB structure changes DB onto production with minimal downtime. For that I'd go with a **Blue Green Deployments** <sup>[1](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html)</sup> .

After your comments I assume that you already have running instance of PostgreSQL and would like to modify the content of the DB by altering file structure directly on a "disk" (in this case PVC).

Modifying data structure directly on disk is not the best idea if we are speaking about data integrity, etc.

The reasons for that statement are explained in this article <sup>[2](https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/where-and-how-is-your-data-actually-stored-on-disk)</sup>. It describes how exactly postgreSQL stores data on disk.

> PostgreSQL (by default) writes blocks of data (what PostgreSQL calls pages) to disk in 8k chunks.

Additionally, there is a relation between table and file_path, so postgresql knows which exactly file stores which table.

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('test_data');  
pg_relation_filepath  
----------------------  
base/20886/186770
```

In this example the file `/database/base/20866/186770` contains the actual data for the table `test_data`.

> What is the right way to update the database instead of logging in to the pod and running queries

However, if you sure that you have complete set of files for the DB to operate (like the one you are using during  pg_dump / pg_restore) you can try placing that data on another PVC and recreate pod, however that will still result in a downtime.

Hope that helps.